# Retorno de onPress dentro de components

Tags: react, react-native, componentes

Boa noite.

Estou com um probleminha com o retorno de um OnPress de um TouchableOpacity, dentro de um elemento. Basicamente, às vezes ele retorna a ação, mas, na maioria das vezes não.

O código está assim (resumidamente):

**NewOrder**

```
const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);

{photos !== '' && photos !== null && photos !== undefined ? (<PicturePreview pictures={photos} onPressItem={onDeletePicture} />) : null}

const onDeletePicture = (index) => { //exclui o item do state photos, e setPhotos novamente, com o novo array para renderizar o <PicturePreview/>}
```

O state `photos` é alimentado com a data.uri da foto tirada pela câmera - até aqui, ok, tudo funciona perfeitamente. Quando ele seta valor, ele renderiza o componente `<PicturePreview />`, o qual espero que ele retorne um index do onPress para deletar a uri do array, e assim renderizar novamente.

**PicturePreview:**

```
import PreviewItem from './picturePreviewItem';

const PicturePreview = ({pictures, onPressItem}) => {
  const renderItems = () => {
    if (pictures.length > 0) {
      let elements = [];
      pictures.map((data, index) => {
        if (data !== undefined) {
          elements.push(
            <PreviewItem key={index} index={index} item={data} onPressItem={onPressDelete}/>
          );}
      });
      return elements;
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, pictures.length > 0 ? styles.containerFilled : '',]}>
      {renderItems()}
    </View>
  );
};
```

**PicturePreviewItem:**

```
const PicturePreviewItem = ({item, index, onPressDelete}) => {
  const indexValue = index;
  return (
    <View style={styles.containerPreview}>
      <Image style={styles.imagePreview} resizeMode="contain" source={{uri: item}} />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={(f) => onPressDelete(indexValue)}>
        <Icon name="cancel" style={styles.deletePictureIcon} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Enfim, como disse, às vezes ao clicar no TouchableOpacity, consigo executar a função onDeletePicture da page NewOrder, mas, na maioria das vezes, o press não esboça nenhuma reação.

Todos os imports estão devidamente declarados (react, view, icon, etc…). O problema, pelos testes que fiz com console.log, está no componente PicturePreviewItem, que não responde o onPress (originário de lá) quando acionado.

Obs.: não estou tendo nenhum erro de tela preta.

Obrigado.

Comment: entendeu ???...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seus nomes de passagem de funções estão todos errados, não tem como dar certo mesmo e na verdade não estão funcionando nada, porque se o nome está errado logicamente não deve funcionar nada, preste atenção, quando se passa valor para dentro do componente deve respeita o nome e não é isso que está acontecendo, então:

Componente `PicturePreviewItem`

```
import PicturePreviewItem from './picturePreviewItem';

const PicturePreview = ({pictures, onPressItem}) => {
  const renderItems = () => {
    if (pictures.length > 0) {
      let elements = [];
      pictures.map((data, index) => {        
        elements.push(
            <PicturePreviewItem 
                key={index} index={index} 
                item={data} 
                onPressDelete={onPressItem}
            />
        );
      });
      return elements;
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={[
        styles.container, pictures.length > 0 ? styles.containerFilled : '',
    ]}>
      {renderItems()}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Componente `PicturePreviewItem`

```
const PicturePreviewItem = ({item, index, onPressDelete}) => {  
  return (
    <View style={styles.containerPreview}>
      <Image 
        style={styles.imagePreview}
        resizeMode="contain" 
        source={{uri: item}} />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={(f) => onPressDelete(index)}>
            <Icon name="cancel" style={styles.deletePictureIcon} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

ou seja, os nomes das `props` tem que ser correspondentes e tome cuidado bastante com os seus nomes tudo diferente eu mesmo para analisar acabei ficando perdido e isso também tem relação a sua programação, a mudança foi nos nome das funções tente observar, só não tenho como testar basicamente, mas, vou propor logo abaixo um exemplo em [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) para você ter uma idéia o que muda é o nome evento do botão o resto é a mesma coisa, exemplo minimo:

```js
function Item({item, index, onClickRemove}) {
  return <div>{item.name}<button onClick={() => onClickRemove(index)}>Remover</button></div>;
}
function Items({datas, onClickRemove}) {
  return (
    <div>{datas.length > 0 && datas.map((item, index) =>(<Item item={item} index={index} onClickRemove={onClickRemove}/>))}</div>
  )
}
function App() {
  const initialValues = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'name 1'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'name 2'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'name 3'},
    {'id': 4, 'name': 'name 4'},
    {'id': 5, 'name': 'name 5'}   
  ];
  const [datas, setDatas] = React.useState(initialValues);
  function onClickRemove(index) {
    let items = [...datas];
    items.splice(index, 1);
    setDatas(items);
  }
  function loadInitialValues(){
    setDatas(initialValues);
  }
  return (<div><Items datas={datas} onClickRemove={onClickRemove}/>{datas.length === 0 && <button onClick={loadInitialValues}>Carregar</button>}</div>);
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

e observe bem os nomes são passados para todos os `componentes` com o mesmo nome para manter um padrão.